# Restkit failed to post object

Tags: objective-c, laravel, restkit

I have been using Restkit for GET successfully and now I tried to use it for POST and get error. Here is the code for my RESTKit which I think is quite standard:

```
RKObjectMapping *mappingTransaction = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Transaction class]];
NSDictionary *mappingTransactionDict = @{
                                           @"final_price" : @"finalPrice",
                                           @"discount" : @"discount",
                                           @"customer_fk" : @"customerID",
                                           @"typeofpayment_fk" : @"typeOfPaymentID",
                                           @"shop_fk" : @"shopID",
                                           @"systemuser_fk" : @"systemUserID",
                                           @"company_fk" : @"companyID",
                                           @"created_at" : @"creationDate",
                                           @"updated_at" : @"updateDate"
                                           };
[mappingTransaction addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:mappingTransactionDict];


RKResponseDescriptor *transactionDescriptor =
[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:mappingTransaction
                                             method:RKRequestMethodPOST
                                        pathPattern:@"/revenue/add/transaction"
                                            keyPath:nil
                                        statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptor:transactionDescriptor];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:(Transaction *)transactionRecord
                                       path:@"/revenue/add/transaction"
                                       parameters:nil
                                          success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult){
                                              //self.typeOfPaymentArray = mappingResult.array;
                                          }
                                          failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
                                              NSLog(@"Transaction insert failed': %@", error);
                                          }];
```

Then there's an error of "TokenMismatchException":
[image]

I googled it but seems all threads are talking about CSRF token from a form, which in my case is a third party IOS app. My RESTFul API is run by Laravel 5. Any idea will be appreciated. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Do you have a request descriptor? What is the server expecting and what does it get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you want to map an object (Transaction) in the request (not in the response),  so instead of using `responseDescriptorWithMapping` you should use this method:

```
+ (instancetype)requestDescriptorWithMapping:(RKMapping *)mapping objectClass:(Class)objectClass rootKeyPath:(NSString *)rootKeyPath method:(RKRequestMethod)method
```

Comment: Do I need a requestMapping too?

Comment: yes, if you are sending objects via POST you must.  
Suggestion: to avoid repeat the mapping again i recommend you to use the utility inverseMapping:
requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:[mappingTransaction inverseMapping] objectClass:[Transaction class] rootKeyPath:nil method:RKRequestMethodPOST];

Comment: Maybe you forgot to add the authorization:
 [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].HTTPClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:@"yourusername" password:@"yourpassword"];

Comment: Apparently this could be related to a requirement in Laravel 5 that csrf token is required for all post requests. I am digging into the document and find out how csrf token can be included into the RESTKit request. Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29620628/laravel-5-ajax-500-error-on-post/29621637#29621637. I will post any finding to this thread. Thanks for all the effort put.

Comment: Finally it works! I have to disable CSRF token checking in my RESTFul backend (Laravel 5).

Comment: Javier - thank you very much I put your recommended configuration (except the authentication part which I haven't implemented yet). Though RESTKit is returning error in debug console, which is not the context of this problem thread. In case anyone hitting similar problem as mine and want to momentarily disable CSRF checking to prove their app working, this is the link: http://laravel.io/forum/11-14-2014-disabling-the-csrf-middleware-in-laravel-5.

Comment: Trying to make this thread complete. I mentioned that I received an error after successful record insert. It is because my RESTFul API wasn't replying in JSON format. To make the whole POST progress complete you may want to receive something from the server side (it is a insert ID in my case). So after making the reply (ID) in JSON format I am able to receive a clean reply from the RESTKit.